# Error while installing Cilk Plus on Mac OS X (El Capitan)

Tags: c++, macos, llvm-clang, cilk, cilk-plus

[image]I have encountered issues while installing the CilkPlus on my Mac OS X.Following the [installation page](http://cilkplus.github.io/), I have executed the following commands in the following order:

```
$mkdir Cilk
$cd Cilk
$git clone -b cilkplus https://github.com/cilkplus/llvm llvm
$git clone -b cilkplus https://github.com/cilkplus/clang llvm/tools/clang
$git clone -b cilkplus https://github.com/cilkplus/compiler-rt llvm/projects/compiler-rt
```

Then,

```
$cd llvm    
$mkdir build && cd build
$cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DINTEL_SPECIFIC_CILKPLUS=1 --DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Binary2 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \ -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ ..
```

However, it ended with errors.[ErroLog](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3h_Bzq6r5nrRzFxVGdOUXlLRjQ/view?usp=sharing%20https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3h_Bzq6r5nreXBOa3JyS0NKRDQ/view?usp=sharing) [ErrorLog3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3h_Bzq6r5nrRzFxVGdOUXlLRjQ/view?usp=sharing%20https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3h_Bzq6r5nreXBOa3JyS0NKRDQ/view?usp=sharing). It would be great if someone can let me know where I am wrong. I am trying to compile and execute CilkPlus code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your c++ compiler cannot compile/run this check.

```
#include <atomic>
std::atomic<int> x;
int main() {
  return x;
}
```

It would be a good starting point to check if your system has the latest compilers and Xcode.